# R. Incorrect prediction using survey, splines and only one value of the independent variable

Tags: r, spline, survey, bspline

When I try to get a prediction for just one value of the independent variable using this syntax:

```
library(survey)
library(splines)
data(api)
dclus <- svydesign(id=~dnum,data=apiclus2)
log<-svyglm(api99 ~  bs(ell,degree=1, knots =c(14,23)) , dclus)
data <- data.frame(ell = 0)
data <- cbind(data, predict(log, newdata=data))
data <- data.frame(ell = 15)
data <- cbind(data, predict(log, newdata=data))
```

I get always the same prediction:

```
#link=591.0929
```

This does not happen if I only use survey or spline or if I create a data frame with a list of independent values:

```
data<-data.frame(ell = rep(seq(from = 0, to = 66)))
data <- cbind(data, predict(log, newdata=data))
```

Curiously enough, in this last data frame link=591.0929 corresponds to ell=23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the `bs()` term doesn't fully specify the basis -- it also uses the range of the predictor to work out boundary knots. With only one point, the way it does this doesn't work.

A work-around is to specify the boundary knots, eg,

```
> log<-svyglm(api99 ~  bs(ell,degree=1, knots =c(14,23), Boundary.knots=c(0,100)) , dclus)
> data <- data.frame(ell = 0)
>  predict(log, newdata=data)
    link     SE
1 787.64 27.162
> data2 <- data.frame(ell = 15)
>  predict(log, newdata=data2)
    link     SE
1 627.76 34.108
```

It looks as though `predict.lm` has some complicated stuff to stop this happening that wasn't there when `predict.svyglm` was written.

I'll pass this on to the package maintainer ;-)

Comment: Thank you. How does one choose the boundary knots?

Comment: The `bs()` function uses the minimum and maximum of the data, so the outer two spline intervals run exactly to the edge of the data. It's  valid to have them further out or closer in, you just get slightly different splines.